# Why does \text only affect next charater, but \cal affects all that follow

Tags: fonts

I am sure this is indicative of a more general idea, but I noticed that if I put in

```
 $$\text hello$$
 $$\text {hello}$$

 $$\cal OU$$
 $$\cal {OU}$$
```

to my tex and compile I get the following output

[image]

Clearly in the first case the \text command has only affected the first character unless braces are used, whereas in the other case all charcters are affected.

> Is there a reason as to why these behave differently? Is there a general rule as to which commands will act which way?

Thanks for any help in advance. Also, I am not sure which tag to use - please do add anything relevant.

Comment: related: [The scope of LaTeX commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6497/579)

Comment: the recommended command to get calligraphic is \mathcal which like \text takekes an argument \mathcal{A}  not {\cal A}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This difference in behavior has been taken into account almost twenty years ago, when LaTeX2e was released (later simply called LaTeX).

The command `\cal` has been deprecated since June 1994, and `\mathcal` is to be preferred. Like `\text`, `\mathcal` is a command with an argument and its effect holds only for the material in braces that follows it.

So

```
$\text{hello}\ne\mathcal{O}$
```

is valid and supported input. By rule of TeX, if a command with argument is not followed by `{`, the *first* token is used as the argument. This is why the manual insists that arguments should ***always*** be enclosed in braces.

Notice also that `$$` is not to be used in LaTeX. The manual doesn't mention it; people use it, but they're wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for letting me know about mathcal. And I know about $$, but mathjax doesn't seem to accept \[..\] yet, so when I am online I am not in that habit.

Comment: @JoeTait I consider a big nuisance that MathJax doesn't accept `\[...\]`, but there may be technical reasons for this.

Comment: MathJax *does* accept `\[...\]`, but StackExchange has disabled it because of bad interactions with Markdown.

Comment: @DavideCervone They should disable `$$` and favor `\begin{displaymath}` or `\begin{equation}` instead.

Comment: At this point it is probably too late, as there is substantial content with `$$`, and from the standpoint of ease of typing, I suspect most users on the SE sites that offer MathJax would prefer `$$` to the longer `\begin{...}` forms.  These are mainly people trying to get some math into their posts, not TeX purists as I would expect is more the case here.  In any case, I have nothing to do with making the decisions at SE.